# signInWithPopup does not open a popup window. Instead, it opens a new tab

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

The code below does not open a pop-up window.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup( ... )
```

Anyone has any idea, please help me?

I am using chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Chrome 59: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=723655